# Использование селекторов CSS

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.
У меня есть две строки "Меню_верхнее" и "Меню_нижнее". Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на нижнюю строку оставался hover-эффект у верхнего меню. Исходный код скинул, пытался сделать, но не получилось... Думаю, что ошибка где-то на 16 строке. [Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/Lex1992/no1a1Ly3/4/) ссылка. Что не так? Спасибо!

```
<html>
<style>
ul {list-style: none;}
#y-switch {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul #y-switch:hover + ul #y-switcher, #y-switcher:hover {
    top: 34.9px;
    opacity: 1;
}
#y-switcher {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#y-switch:hover, ul #y-switch > ul:hover {
    background: #ffeba0;
}
</style>
<body>
<ul class="container">
    <li><span id="y-switch">Меню_верхнее</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span id="y-switcher">Меню_нижнее</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: примерно так https://jsfiddle.net/cfysh1j8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#y-switch {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul #y-switch:hover + ul #y-switcher,
#y-switcher:hover {
  top: 34.9px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#y-switcher {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#y-switch:hover,
ul #y-switch > ul:hover {
  background: #ffeba0;
}

/* добавлено */
ul.container:hover > li span#y-switch {
  background: #ffeba0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li><span id="y-switch">Меню_верхнее</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span id="y-switcher">Меню_нижнее</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!